# Use Generic Interface Without Specifc Types?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following setup where I'm creating a registry of my interfaces but I don't know how to get away with using generics.  The below of course gives me a compile error.  What is the proper way to set something like this up?  I will have multiple implementations of MyInterface, so I want to be able to access them at run time from a registry.

```
public interface MyInterface<T1, T2> {
}

public static class ApiEntityMapperRegistry {
        private static Dictionary<Type, Type> registry = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

        public static void Register<T2, T3>() {
            if (!registry.ContainsKey(typeof(T2))) {
                registry.Add(typeof(T2), typeof(T3));
            }
        }        

        // this method doesn't compile
        public static MyInterface<T1, T2> GetMapper(){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Or perhaps there is a better approach all together?

Comment: the `GetMapper()` should also have the generic typearguments perhaps? `GetMapper<T1,T2>()`

Comment: what is 'IApiEntityMapper<T1,T2>'?

Comment: @AdrianNasui - Fixed... It's MyInterface

Comment: would be useful to have your compile error

Comment: Proper way? It's unclear exactly what you want to do, but I believe you are looking for IOC container, such as ninject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your code to compile use generic method definition:

```
public static IApiEntityMapper<T1, T2> GetMapper<T1, T2>(){
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @AdamLevitt Unfortunately it is relevant for the return type, so it becomes relevant to the overall method

Comment: @AdamLevitt Since C# is statically typed, and generic types are not dynamic types, you still need to have all the necessary information for the return type. Otherwise, you can just return a `Type` and then need to cast it later; but that will still require you to know the target type.